# ipdb.set_trace inside __set__ descriptor does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipdb

I'm trying to debug/understand the Django's API to build my own ORM. I've changed set and get descriptors from Fields to do what I want (validate when I set the object). Here's the code:

```py
def __set__(self, obj, value):
        self.value = self.clean(value)
```

Some Fields are bugged because I've changed a lot of things inside it, and it crashes when I set the object.
When I try to debug like:

```py
def __set__(self, obj, value):
        import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()
        self.value = self.clean(value)
```

the python stalls and I can't do nothing but stop the process than kill it or just close the terminal.

Does anyone know why ipdb can't handle this kind of call?

Comment: Have you tried using just plain PDB? It could be an issue where Django is starting a thread/process, and ipdb is pausing that, but not the main process.

Comment: Please always use the generic [python] tag for all python questions